# Nested *ngFor from object with list of objects

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a property in a component named `companies`:

```ts
companies: Company[];
```

Each company has a list of `products`:

```ts
export class Company {
  id: number; //my own class
  name: string;

  products: Product[] = []; //company have products
                            //Product is a diffrent object like Company
}
```

But when I retrieve data (`company` with `products`), the `products` list doesn't have a type (`Product` are `Object` now).

In the component's template I want to create a nested `*ngFor` like this:

```html
<mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel-header
    *ngFor="let company of companies"
  >
    <mat-panel-title>{{ company.name }}</mat-panel-title>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <mat-selection-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let product of companies.products">
      {{ product.name }}
    </mat-list-item>
  </mat-selection-list>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

However, I get an error in the console:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined

The list of companies are displaying ok, but without the related products in the company.

My question is, how to code the `*ngFor` properly to get those products (related to companies) in my component's template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to nest `*ngFor`s. `companies` is an array and does not have `products` property but `company` does. And please note that I moved the first `*ngFor` from panel header tag to panel tag.

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let company of companies">

     <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>{{ company.name }}</mat-panel-title>
     </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <mat-selection-list>
       <mat-list-item *ngFor="let product of company.products">
          {{ product.name }}
       </mat-list-item>
    </mat-selection-list>

</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Answer (score 2):

As each company has products you have to list the products at the company level. Your HTML would then need to be nested so that `company` has scope when you retrieve the products.

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let company of companies">

  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>{{ company.name }}</mat-panel-title>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>

  <mat-selection-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let product of company.products">
      {{ product.name }}
    </mat-list-item>
  </mat-selection-list> 

</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Other alternative to this approach could be:

- flatten the products into its own list across companies.
- Select a company and then display the products of the selected company

Answer (score 0):

let product of company.products

EDIT

sorry, I didn't notice that the the second ngFor wasn't under the outer ngFor.
I'm not entirely well versed in angular-material but I'll take a look real quick and let you know if I have a good solution for you

EDIT

You want to put your ngFor in the mat-expansion-panel, not in the mat-expansion-panel-header.  and then let product of company.products

Comment: Not work, sorry. Still undefined. I not marked your answer down, idk who do that

Comment: No worries, some people do that :-)   I've updated my answer

Comment: If you dont want to lose rep, just delete it

Comment: Or, when seeing that my edit actually answers the question, update the downvote?

Comment: Lol. Appreciated. I've lurked here for a long time and finally decided to post for a bit but it's felt a bit... Hostile?  People are really clamoring for rep, I guess